# Symfony / Doctrine Error: "Class 'FROM' is not defined." on getResult()

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-query, symfony-3.2

I'm developing my first symfony app andwhile trying to use the queryBuilder I've been struggling with an issue for a couple of hours.

I'm trying to execute a SQL query and I get the following error:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 288 near 'FROM StatsBundle\Entity\PlayerRealMatch': Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined."

Basically I'm storing soccer players ratings and goals and now I'd like to retrieve an aggregation of that, with sums and averages.

I'm inside a service, and I'm calling a method inside my PlayerRealMatchRepository, the core code of this method is the following:

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('prm');
        $qb->select(
            "SUM(prm.has_started) as tit,
            SUM(prm.has_entered) as rempl,
            SUM(prm.yellow_cards) as yc,
            SUM(prm.red_card) as rc,
            SUM(prm.goals) AS gf,
            SUM(prm.own_goals) as ga,
            AVG(prm.rating) as avg"
        )
            ->innerJoin('prm.realMatch', 'rm')
            ->where('prm.playerId = :idPlayer')
            ->groupBy('rm.season')
            ->setParameter('idPlayer', $player->getId())
            ->getQuery();
        $query =$qb->getQuery();
        $seasonData = $query->getResult();
```

If I look inside the _dql property of the $query object with my debugger, here's what I have:

```
SELECT SUM(prm.has_started) as tit,
                SUM(prm.has_entered) as rempl,
                SUM(prm.yellow_cards) as yc,
                SUM(prm.red_card) as rc,
                SUM(prm.goals) AS gf,
                SUM(prm.own_goals) as ga,
                AVG(prm.rating) as avg 
FROM StatsBundle\Entity\PlayerRealMatch prm 
INNER JOIN prm.realMatch rm 
WHERE prm.playerId = :idPlayer 
GROUP BY rm.season
```

It doesn't look that bad to me, do you guys have any clue of what's wrong here ?

*Note*: Here is an example of the query I'm trying to achieve and which works flawlessly directly on my DB :

```
SELECT SUM(prm.has_started) as tit,
                SUM(prm.has_entered) as rempl,
                SUM(prm.yellow_cards) as yc,
                SUM(prm.red_card) as rc,
                SUM(prm.goals) AS gf,
                SUM(prm.own_goals) as ga,
                AVG(prm.rating) as avg 
FROM player_real_match prm 
INNER JOIN real_match rm ON prm.real_match_id = rm.id 
WHERE prm.player_id = 327 
GROUP BY rm.season;
```

**Details below**

3 entities:

- Player
- RealMatch : general data about the match
- PlayerRealMatch : performance of a player inside a match

Here's below an extract of their respective configurations to show how they are linked.

```
StatsBundle\Entity\Player: 
...
    manyToOne:
        real_team:
            targetEntity: RealTeam
            inversedBy: players
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: CASCADE
                name: real_team_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    oneToMany:
        player_real_matches:
            targetEntity: PlayerRealMatch
            mappedBy: player 
...
```

---

```
StatsBundle\Entity\RealMatch:
...
    home_team:
        targetEntity: RealTeam
        inversedBy: home_matches
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: CASCADE
            name: home_team_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    away_team:
        targetEntity: RealTeam
        inversedBy: away_matches
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: CASCADE
            name: away_team_id
            referencedColumnName: id
oneToMany:
    player_real_matches:
        targetEntity: PlayerRealMatch
        mappedBy: real_match
...
```

---

```
StatsBundle\Entity\PlayerRealMatch:
...
manyToOne:
    real_match:
        targetEntity: RealMatch
        inversedBy: player_real_matches
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: CASCADE
            name: real_match_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    player:
        targetEntity: Player
        inversedBy: player_real_matches
        joinColumn:
            onDelete: CASCADE
            name: player_id
            referencedColumnName: id
...
```

---

Call to repository method from the service

```
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $this->aggregatePlayerData($player, $match);
    }

    private function aggregatePlayerData(Player $player, RealMatch $match)
    {
        $playerStats = $this->_em
            ->getRepository('StatsBundle:PlayerRealMatch')
            ->getAggregatedStats($player, $match);
    }

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->_em = $entityManager;
}
```

And here is the services.yml about my service

```
stats.aggregator:
    class: StatsBundle\Service\Aggregator
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Repository Method

```
 /**
 * getAggregatedStats
 *
 * @param $player the player entity
 * @param RealMatch $match  the real match entity
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAggregatedStats($player, RealMatch $match)
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('prm');
    $qb->select(
        "SUM(prm.has_started) as tit,
        SUM(prm.has_entered) as rempl,
        SUM(prm.yellow_cards) as yc,
        SUM(prm.red_card) as rc,
        SUM(prm.goals) AS gf,
        SUM(prm.own_goals) as ga,
        AVG(prm.rating) as avg"
    )
    ->from('StatsBundle:PlayerRealMatch', 'prm')
    ->innerJoin('prm.realMatch', 'rm')
    ->where('prm.playerId = :idPlayer')
    ->groupBy('rm.season')
    ->setParameter('idPlayer', $player->getId())
    ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $seasonData = $query->getResult();

    return $seasonData;
}
```

Sorry for the long post, I tried to document it as clearly as I could.
Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to use reserved sql word for column name,
try changing

```
"AVG(prm.rating) as avg" -> "AVG(prm.rating) as avgRating"
```

Comment: I had the same problem, except I was using "count". This saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue, I believe it was a classic beginner's mistake:

On my select instruction, I was using lower_case attributes, because this is how my SQL columns are formatted.

However this is not the case of my entities properties. So here is the correct syntax for my select instruction

```
   "SUM(prm.hasStarted) as tit,
    SUM(prm.hasEntered) as rempl,
    SUM(prm.yellowCards) as yc,
    SUM(prm.redCard) as rc,
    SUM(prm.goals) as gf,
    SUM(prm.ownGoals) as ga,
    AVG(prm.rating) as avg"
```

So the conclusion is: when doing DQL, always refer to your entities properties and not to your DB columns.

The error message was weird though, I would have liked something more explicit like "the entity X has no property Y"

Thanks a lot Azam Alvi for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You did not give from field in your query try to do like this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('prm');
    $qb->select(
        "SUM(prm.has_started) as tit,
        SUM(prm.has_entered) as rempl,
        SUM(prm.yellow_cards) as yc,
        SUM(prm.red_card) as rc,
        SUM(prm.goals) AS gf,
        SUM(prm.own_goals) as ga,
        AVG(prm.rating) as avg"
    )
        ->from('StatsBundle:PlayerRealMatch ', 'prm') // this one is missing
        ->innerJoin('prm.realMatch', 'rm')
        ->where('prm.playerId = :idPlayer')
        ->groupBy('rm.season')
        ->setParameter('idPlayer', $player->getId());

    $seasonData = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in fact I already tried that without success, still the same error.

From my understanding, this is implicitly done by :

    $this->createQueryBuilder('prm');

since I'm on PlayerRealMatchRepository. And it actually shows on my _dql

Comment: can you show me that full function code for this query. Also show me the code how you are calling this function from repo.

Comment: I updated the original post's description with what you're asking

Comment: why are you calling `->getQuery()` function two time? remove first one

Comment: I'm doing that for debugging purposes, I wanted to the the query...
Just changed into 
    $seasonData[$player->getId()] = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
But of course it doesn't change anything

Comment: try to put exit code after first `->getQuery(); exit;` then let me know if some error comes of not

Comment: No, nothing crashes, it the getResult() statement that raises an exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138518/discussion-between-azam-alvi-and-smashed).